# Getting Error Could not evaluate: No ability to determine if volume exists

Tags: puppet

I'm getting this error when running puppet `puppet agent -t`:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Environment/Environment::Createenv[shared2]/Volume[shared2]: Could not evaluate: No ability to determine if volume exists
Error: /Stage[main]/Environment/Environment::Createenv[shared1]/Volume[shared1]: Could not evaluate: No ability to determine if volume exists
```

Here is the code for environment/manifest/init.pp

```
class environment(){
            volume { "${title}":
              ensure      => present,
              location    => "/home",
              mode        => 0750,
              owner       => "${title}",
              group       => "env",
              device_name => undef,
              device_size => 10,
              az          => undef,
              instance_id => undef,
            }
}
```

And the provider file (lib/puppet/provider/ebs.rb):

```
require 'puppet/resource'
require 'puppet/resource/catalog'
require 'fileutils'
require 'rubygems'
require 'facter'
require 'aws-sdk'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/aws-config'
include Puppet::Util::Volume
include AwsConfig

Puppet::Type.type(:volume).provide(:ebs) do
  desc "Create, attach, format and mount EBS volumes"

  defaultfor :kernel => "Linux"

  def create
    az = Facter.value('ec2_placement_availability_zone')
    puts "Some code here ..."
  end

  def destroy
    raise NotImplementedError
  end

  def exists?
    return File.directory?(@resource[:name])
  end

end
```

And the type (lib/puppet/type/volume.rb):

```
require 'puppet/type'
Puppet::Type.newtype(:volume) do
  @doc = "Create new volume. Limited to EBS volumes"

  ensurable do
    self.defaultvalues
    defaultto :present
  end

  newparam(:name) do
    desc "Name of resource"
    isnamevar
  end

  newparam(:location) do
    desc "path to directory where the volume will be mounted"
  end
end
```

Puppet version 3.0.1 (server and client). Any idea anyone ? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!

simply moved the provider file to a dir having the same name as type. in my case /etc/puppet/modules/environment/lib/puppet/provider/**volume**/ebs.rb

where *environment* is the name of my custom module and *volume* is the custom type.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!